# Append an asterisk to the sibling of a div that contains a label with the class of .mandatory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wish to append and asterisk to the next sibling of a div that contains a label with a class of mandatory. This is to signify that a form field is required.

This mandatory marker works with the following code:

```
jQuery('label.mandatory').parent().next().append('<span class="mandatory-marker">&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');
```

When the HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="formdetails p_3">
    <div class="label">
        <label for="p_3" class="mandatory" id="p_3ErrorMessage">Sexuality</label>
    </div>
    <div class="detail" id="ext-gen13">
        <div class="x-form-field-wrap x-form-field-trigger-wrap" id="ext-gen15" style="width: 194px;">
            <input type="hidden" id="ext-gen17" name="p_3" value="">
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="24" id="ext-gen14" class="x-form-text x-form-field" style="width: 169px;">
            <img class="x-form-trigger x-form-arrow-trigger" alt="" src="#" id="ext-gen16">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="2385" name="p_id3">
    </div>
</div>
```

However, in some cases the HTML is slightly different if the form field is a textarea rather than a textbox:

```
<div class="formdetails p_1">
    <div class="label">
        <label for="p_1" class="mandatory" id="p_1ErrorMessage">CV</label>
    </div>
    <div class="detail">
        <div class="fileinputs">
              <input type="file" class="file icams-field-text required  textfield" autocomplete="off" id="p_1" name="p_1">
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="2376" name="p_id1">
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case I wish to append the mandatory script the file inputs div so have written the following jQuery script to first check that the fileinputs div exists and if so attempt to append the mandatory marker to it. If not, it should emulate the behavior of my script above:

```
jQuery('label.mandatory').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().find('div.fileinputs').length){
        $(this).parent().next().find('div.fileinputs').append('<span class="mandatory-marker">&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().next().append('<span class="mandatory-marker">&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');
    }
})
```

This does not seem to work though for some reason. I believe it may be due to the find function not working correctly. I have also tried closest here.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to what may be doing wrong?

A working fiddle can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/qRG57/

Many have complained that jQuery is unnecessary here so to clear up those comments, IE7 support is required so I cannot use modern CSS selectors. This is why I am having to do a lot of DOM manipulation with my jQuery rather than simply using CSS selectors.

Comment: Why can't you use `:before` on `.mandatory` and style it that way?

Comment: Because I don't want the marker appearing on or associated with the label, it needs to appear to be on the field itself.

Comment: This is bad use of jQuery, look at all that DOM iteration and manual HTML manipulation! As @BeatAlex says just use `:before` or `:after`. Don't use `&nbsp` for spacing either. You can treat these pseudo elements as normal elements and make them appear where you want.

Comment: You don't seem to understand. Using label.mandatory:after would append the mandatory marker to the right of the label. It needs to be to the right of the associated input field which is contained within div.detail. This is not a bad use of jQuery as jQuery is designed for DOM manipulation. Also the original HTML cannot be edited as this is the default way our system handles this and we cannot alter it as it would affect other clients. Also IE7 support is required meaning modern CSS selectors cannot be used in this case.

Comment: @jezzipin You should have told us that it had to work in IE7 originally.

Comment: I pasted it into codepen instead of jsFiddle and it worked. No idea why it's not working in jsFiddle. http://codepen.io/BeatAlex/pen/bhqIF

Comment: It isn't working as desired. The mandatory marker for the file input field should be a child of the .fileinputs div rather than appearing outside of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear on my if condition that the .next() was missing so instead of looking at label.mandatory's parent sibling it was looking at the parent instead.

```
jQuery('label.mandatory').each(function(){
    if($(this).parent().next().find('div.fileinputs').length){
        $(this).parent().next().find('div.fileinputs').append('<span class="mandatory-marker">&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');
    }else{
        $(this).parent().next().append('<span class="mandatory-marker">&nbsp;&nbsp;*&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I understand you want it in the field so hopefully this works.

Use

```
.mandatory:before{
    content:" * ";
    /* more styles to align the asterisk properly */
}
```

You don't need to be using jQuery in this case, just plain CSS.

Edit: I was using `input:required:before` but remembered that inputs don't support `:before` or `:after` css :(

Comment: I do need to use jQuery as IE7 support is required otherwise I wouldn't be using jQuery.

Comment: @jezzipin put that in the first post then!